# Ensure destroy function is called

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

Somebody use shared pointer to ensure that the aforementioned handle are destroyed when it's no longer needed.

In practice, the implementation of `InitDemoStruct()` `DestroyStruct()` `struct DemoStruct` are opaque to me.They are provided by others.

Although this code snippet **works as expected**, but it **looks strange indeed**:

It's commonly seen that a smart pointer points to a specific class or struct, e.g: `std::shared_ptr<struct DemoSt> ptr2object`; Recently, I saw such usage. Use smart pointer to pointer to a pointer of a specific class or struct, e.g:`std::shared_ptr<struct DemoSt*> ptr2point_of_object`;

**UPDATED**: There is an answer provided by `nwp`.

Here is the aforementioned [code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/3v8MjEd7E):

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct DemoStruct;
using DemoStructHandle = DemoStruct* ;

//In practice, the implementation of  `InitDemoStruct()` `DestroyStruct()` `struct DemoStruct` is opaque to me.
//They are provided by others.
struct DemoStruct{
};


void InitDemoStruct(DemoStructHandle* handle_ptr){
    *handle_ptr = new DemoStruct(); 
    //may do some other meaningful init in InitDemoStruct(); 
    };


void DestroyStruct(DemoStructHandle* handle_ptr){
    std::cout << "Destroy() is called" << std::endl;
    if(handle_ptr==nullptr){
        return;
    }

    delete *handle_ptr;
}

//I use shared pointer to ensure that the aforementioned handle is destroyed when it's no longer needed.
std::shared_ptr<DemoStructHandle> MakeDemoStructHandlePtr(void)
{  
    return std::shared_ptr<DemoStructHandle>(new DemoStructHandle(nullptr), [](DemoStructHandle* pHandle){
        DestroyStruct(pHandle);
        delete pHandle;});
}


int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<DemoStructHandle> demo_class_handle_ptr = MakeDemoStructHandlePtr();
    InitDemoStruct(demo_class_handle_ptr.get());           
}
```

Comment: Not sure what your question is here - can you clarify?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Adrian Mole Although this code snippet works as expected(i.e. ensure to call the `destroy()`), but it looks strange indeed. The shared pointer is not valid  initialised when it's constructed.

Comment: Is `DemoStructHandle` also opaque, or is it officially a pointer to `DemoStruct`?

Comment: @j6t `DemoStructHandle` is officially a pointer to `DemoStruct`. `DemoStructHandle` is not opaque whereas DemoStruct is opaque.

Comment: @AdrianMole The problem in the demo code is that it's **complicated** to use, you need to **explicitly call** `InitDemoStruct(demo_class_handle_ptr.get()); ` after is shared pointer who manages a `nullptr` has been constructed.

Comment: @John So what is the question? Because you did not say the question was, I will assume you meant to ask how to make it a normal smart pointer, instead of a smart pointer to another pointer.

Comment: @user253751 The problem in the demo code is that it's **complicated** to use, you need to **explicitly call** InitDemoStruct(demo_class_handle_ptr.get());  after **a shared pointer who manages a `nullptr` has been constructed**.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a C++ wrapper around a C opaque handle.

In one file, it *is* strange, but when `DemoStructHandle` is the only complete type, you (intentionally) can't do much better.

Comment: What about my answer?

Comment: @John isn't shared. That would be an ok `unique_ptr` replacement. Are there any functions that need access to `handle` other than init and destroy?

Comment: I agree with you.

Comment: I'd call your wrapper a smart pointer.

Comment: Why, there is no smart pointer indeed.

Comment: @John `Wrarper_without_smartptr` *is* a smart pointer if you expose `handle`

Comment: Sorry for my poor English. Wrarper_without_smartptr is a smart pointer **if you expose handle**.Could you please explain that in more detail for me? Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243381/discussion-between-caleth-and-john).

Comment: I think this [one](https://godbolt.org/z/jqTo9G6eM) is much better. How do you think about it.

Answer (score 1):

My answer:

```
class Wrarper_without_smartptr    
{
    public:
        Wrarper_without_smartptr(){
            InitDemoStruct(&handle);
        }

        Wrarper_without_smartptr(const Wrarper_without_smartptr&) = delete;
        Wrarper_without_smartptr operator=(const Wrarper_without_smartptr&)= delete;

        ~Wrarper_without_smartptr(){
            DestroyStruct(&handle);
        }

    private:
        DemoStructHandle handle;
};
```

***UPDATED***:
Maybe this [one](https://godbolt.org/z/jqTo9G6eM) is much better:

```
class WrapperWithSmartPointer2Handle {
      public:
        WrapperWithSmartPointer2Handle()
                : handle_ptr(new DemoStructHandle(nullptr),
                             [](DemoStructHandle* handle_ptr) { DestroyStruct(handle_ptr); }) {
            InitDemoStruct(handle_ptr.get());
        }
    
        DemoStructHandle operator*() { return *handle_ptr; }
        DemoStructHandle operator->() { return *handle_ptr;}
    
      private:
        std::shared_ptr<DemoStructHandle> handle_ptr;
    };
```

Comment: code only answers arent nice. You should explain how this code helps to answer the question

Answer (score 1):

I assume your question is how to avoid the double indirection (pointer-to-pointer). You can do that like this:

```
std::shared_ptr<DemoStruct> MakeDemoStructPtr(/*void not required in C++*/)
{  
    DemoStruct *pHandle;
    InitDemoStruct(&pHandle);
    return std::shared_ptr<DemoStruct>(pHandle,
        [](DemoStruct *pHandle){
            DestroyStruct(&pHandle);
        }
    );
}


int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<DemoStruct> demo_class_handle_ptr = MakeDemoStructPtr();
}
```

The shared_ptr points to a DemoStruct instead of pointing to a DemoStructHandle.

If `InitDemoStruct` has more arguments, you can add the arguments to `MakeDemoStructPtr`

Comment: Sorry for my poor English. There is a problem with your solution. `DemoStruct` is opaque to me. I think `std::shared_ptr<DemoStruct>` does not compile. How do you think about it?

Comment: @John Works for me. See https://godbolt.org/z/sTP9r7jq4 - I haven't even defined DemoStruct

Comment: It's amazing. I see. I know where I am wrong. I don't have to create an object of `DemoStruct` by `new DemoStruct` indeed. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `shared_ptr` like this:

```
struct DemoStructDeleter {
    void operator()(DemoStructHandle p) {
        DemoStructDestroy(&p);
    }
};

// in some function:
DemoStructHandle h;
InitDemoStruct(&h);
std::shared_ptr<DemoStruct> smartptr(h, DemoStructDeleter{});
// do something with smartptr
```

Note that it is not `shared_ptr<DemoStructHandle>`, because you do not want to have a smart pointer to the handle, but to the struct itself.

If you wrap this in a factory function, you need not have an explicit `DemoStructDeleter`, but can use a lambda function.

Comment: `DemoStruct` is opaque to me. I think `std::shared_ptr<DemoStruct>` does not compile. How do you think about it?

Comment: @John `shared_ptr` can hold pointers to incomplete types. The only time they must be complete is when `default_delete` is used. When you do not use it, like in my example, you never need a complete `DemoStruct`.

Comment: Any potential problem when `DemoStructHandle h` is out of range\block whereas `std::shared_ptr<DemoStruct> smartptr` still points to the address of `DemoStructHandle h`? Just like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/qGsEYP85T).

Comment: @John that isn't a problem, because we only need the *value* of `h`, not the object `h` itself

Comment: @Caleth I see. Thank you. But I still think such code is hard to fully understand.